How to create graph in kibana to visualize apis and their response times with respect to timestamps?
I have logs containing fields api and their response_time and every log contains timestamp associated with it like when it is generated. Now i want to generate a graph to view the timestamps on X-axis and response_time on Y-axis. But I want to see the apis also. I can view timestamp vs responsetime but i can't see the apis here. How to view them?
I had selected under the metrics Y-axis section the response_time and Aggreation as Top Hit,Field=response_time ,aggregate with=concatenate, size=1 ans Sorted based on timestamp descending. And on the Add buckets, I added X-axis and selected the aggregation as Date Histogram and field=timestamp and minimum interval =milliseconds. Now I can view the responsetime at the particular timestamp.
I expect to view the apis along with their response_time at that timestamp. If there are more than one api at the timestamp view all those apis.
